# Nancy Views Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, nancy, self-hosting

I'm hosting Nancy in my Console Application, and when I try to call a view(for example "Login.html") the page gives me error 500. This is the code:

```
public sealed class LoginModule : NancyModule
{
    private readonly DatabaseList _db = Singleton.DB;
    public LoginModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = x => View["Login.html"];
    }
}
```

I implemented my own bootstrap because I need sessions:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        var directoryInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory;
        if (directoryInfo != null)
            Environment.CurrentDirectory = directoryInfo.FullName;
        CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);
        Conventions.ViewLocationConventions.Add((viewName, model, viewLocationContext) => String.Concat("Views/", viewName));
    }
}
```

This is the tree of my project:
Various paths;

- WebControllers/

  - LoginModule.cs
  - Nancy.cs
- Views/

  - Login.html

I tried removing all the combinations removing CurrentDirectory, ViewLocationConventions, every type of path like /Views/, ../Views/ etc, but still nothing. I also tried to put the Views path inside WebControllers, or even only the Index.html file, still nothing. In conclusion I also tried to rename Views to Login, nothing to do.

Comment: either change View["Login.html"] to View["Index.html"] or rename the view to Login.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot about mentioning, already tried it too, same error...

Comment: Turn on the [Nancy Diagnostics](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Diagnostics) to see what is the underlying exception...

Comment: I can't understand how to log exceptions or how to see logged messages in the Diagnostics page. Unfortunately docs aren't really well-explained, I find it hard to understand them. The only thing I did is to use the VS debugger, using a breakpoint made me understand that Nancy is raising a ViewNotFoundException. I know nothing more than this.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your view files are set to copy to the output folder and you should be good to go

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand, sorry

Comment: select your views in the solution explorer, go to properties and make sure the `Copy To Output Directory` settings is setup to copy the files to the output folder.